# Trouble with parsing date time format. String not recognized

Tags: c#, datetime

I am having trouble with the parsing of a string value in date Time format.

This is the method where the parsing of the date time format takes place.

```
  internal static DateTime ParseDateTime(string dateTimeString, string[] formats)
    {
        try
        {
            DateTime dateStamp = DateTime.ParseExact(dateTimeString,
                formats, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
            return dateStamp;
        }
        catch (Exception exe)
        {
            var message = $"dateTimeString: '{dateTimeString}', '{string.Join(",", formats)}'.";
            Utility.log(message);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

The formats I am passing in looks like this.

```
 public static string[] DateTimeFormats => new string[]
    {
        "dd-MM-yyyy",
        "MM/dd/yyyy",
        "dd/MM/yyyy",
        "M/d/yyyy",
        "d.M.yyyy",
        "dd.MM.yyyy",
        "MM/dd/yyyy",
        "M/d/yyyy",
        "yyyy/MM/dd",
        "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm tt"
    };
```

I logged the exception and this is the value that results in the error.

```
'20-06-2017 12:00 AM'
```

What am I missing?
Kind regards

Comment: What's the current culture? "AM" isn't universal...

Comment: Also note that "HH" is 24-hour, which is odd to have in a format string with AM/PM. Have you tried "hh" instead?

Comment: Hi there. Will try that thanks. The Culture info is en-ZA

Comment: I think `"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm tt"` should probably be `"dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm tt"`, but I'm not sure that's the problem. You have a bigger issue - How are you going to tell if `01/02/2018` is January 2nd or February 1st? you have both formats in your array...

Comment: @ZoharPeled changing to `hh` does fix it; you should post as an answer; which makes sense - in HH, 12:00 is mid-day - there is no "12:00 am" - there's "00:00 am" and "12:00 pm" when talking HH

Comment: That fixed it. I changes the format to d-MM-yyyy hh:mm. Thank u.

Comment: It is a combination of culture and format string: you have to use "hh" in format string AND use CultureInfo.InvariantCulture. The hh alone does not work everywhere (for example in Germany)

Comment: @Fratyx it works in  en-ZA, though - which is OP's culture :)

Comment: @Marc Gravell: Should it be a local fix or a general solution. I think not all members of SO live in ZA :-)

Comment: @MarcGravell done, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I wrote in my comment (and to be fair, Jon Skeet wrote before me), `"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm tt"` should be `"dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm tt"`.

The `HH` format string is for hours using a 24-hour clock, while
The `hh` format string is for hours using a 12-hour clock.

However, I think you have a bigger issue here, and that is you might parse some strings wrong.
You have in your format array some formats that are interchangeable for some dates - Any date where the day is less than 13 can be parsed with either `"MM/dd/yyyy"` or `"dd/MM/yyyy"` - meaning that `01/02/2018` might be January second 2018 or February 1st 2018.

Comment: As I already said: that solution alone will not work in all countries

Comment: @Fratyx correct. Dates and times are far more complicated then most people realize. When introducing string representations it gets worst. When dealing with multiple cultures it's even harder, and it's even worst then that when you need to handle historical data or daylight savings time. I think the best approach in these cases is to limit your customer to  a strict rule set - otherwise you might find yourself [going crazy.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY)

Comment: Yes, so we generally work only with InvariantCulture. Thank you for the link, I will watch it later when I can use sound.